# Ensure Users Can Only View Their Own Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

This is probably a fundamental question but I know how to restrict access to webpages based on user roles. How do I restrict access to data in the database based on an authenticated user.

For example, assume my application returns transaction data based on a transaction ID HTTP parameter, which is then passed to a getTransactionById method. The user should only be able to view their transactions. How can Spring Security prevent the user from simply changing the ID parameter value in the URL to view other transactions from other users?

Of course, I could manually code the logic to do this but I presume Spring Security has functionality to do this.

Comment: You can run checks using sessions.

Comment: Spring Security ACL might help you check this [tutorial](http://krams915.blogspot.ae/2011/01/spring-security-3-full-acl-tutorial.html)